# Kik: setOrientationLock and statusBar functions failing, and icon not appearing in the side bar

Tags: kik

We're trying to port tekiki.com to Kik using its API, but the code fails on `setOrientationLock` and `statusBar` because the `browser` object is undefined.

We're using http://cdn.kik.com/kik/1.0.9/kik.js'>. The icon also isn't appearing in the side bar even though we have `<link rel='kik-icon' href='/images/dandy/panabee160x160.png'>` in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Is your webapp running in the Kik browser? `kik.browser` is only available inside Kik and is undefined in every other scenario that the webapp might run.

Is the script tag defined above the link tag? This would cause the icon be discovered at run time.